# How to make responsive layout in ionic v1

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ionic-framework, responsive

How do I make a layout for my app using ionic?

I want to make a layout in a responsive grid like this example image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ionic has it's own responsive Grid that you can use, in similar ways as Twitter Bootstrap.

Here is the documentation for v1:

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/components/#grid

Looking at your picture, if you want the inside divs to stack when in portrait, have a look at the 'responsive-sm' class on the documentation above. It should be fairly simple to do exactly what you're after.

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/components/#grid-responsive